# Login / authenticate with WebAPI2

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rest, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

I am attempting to get my Web API 2 REST API to be protected by login. I've been told I should use ASP.Net Identity for this, so I'm muddling through.

I've finally cobbled something together that uses WebAPI 2 / OWIN / NHibernate to create a web service. The templates came with some default API calls. Using these, I was able to successfully register a local account in the database.

Now - I don't know how to "log in" to access the other calls. Is this a very basic thing like passing in headers or data? I don't see any functions in this template that seem to let the user login with the local account.

The original source is 350+ lines of code. I'm just pasting the function definitions for now, but I can expand as needed.

*Update*
I've tried doing things like passing the username / password via JSON. This didn't work. I'm just really unsure of what the framework provides as a method for logging in.

```
' GET api/Account/UserInfo
<HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)>
<Route("UserInfo")>
Public Function GetUserInfo() As UserInfoViewModel

' POST api/Account/Logout
<Route("Logout")>
Public Function Logout() As IHttpActionResult


' GET api/Account/ManageInfo?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
<Route("ManageInfo")>
Public Async Function GetManageInfo(returnUrl As String, Optional generateState As Boolean = False) As Task(Of ManageInfoViewModel)


' POST api/Account/ChangePassword
<Route("ChangePassword")>
Public Async Function ChangePassword(model As ChangePasswordBindingModel) As Task(Of IHttpActionResult)


' POST api/Account/SetPassword
<Route("SetPassword")>
Public Async Function SetPassword(model As SetPasswordBindingModel) As Task(Of IHttpActionResult)


' POST api/Account/AddExternalLogin
<Route("AddExternalLogin")>
Public Async Function AddExternalLogin(model As AddExternalLoginBindingModel) As Task(Of IHttpActionResult)


' POST api/Account/RemoveLogin
<Route("RemoveLogin")>
Public Async Function RemoveLogin(model As RemoveLoginBindingModel) As Task(Of IHttpActionResult)


' GET api/Account/ExternalLogin
<OverrideAuthentication>
<HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)>
<AllowAnonymous>
<Route("ExternalLogin", Name := "ExternalLogin")>
Public Async Function GetExternalLogin(provider As String, Optional [error] As String = Nothing) As Task(Of IHttpActionResult)


' GET api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
<AllowAnonymous>
<Route("ExternalLogins")>
  Public Function GetExternalLogins(returnUrl As String, Optional generateState As Boolean = False) As IEnumerable(Of ExternalLoginViewModel)

' POST api/Account/Register
<AllowAnonymous>
<Route("Register")>
Public Async Function Register(model As RegisterBindingModel) As Task(Of IHttpActionResult)


' POST api/Account/RegisterExternal
<OverrideAuthentication>
<HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)>
<Route("RegisterExternal")>
Public Async Function RegisterExternal(model As RegisterExternalBindingModel) As Task(Of IHttpActionResult)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources @Kevin provided have been quite helpful, but his response does not directly answer the question.

In short: the template I have shown the code for does not currently allow for local login. It appears I would have to set up my own Authoriztion server, or use an external OAuth2 provider (like Google, or Facebook). Once I have more time, I will update this post with the actual fix / code changes that would make this a fully working implementation.

Comment: Are you still busy?

Comment: Always :). Unfortunately, I never came up with a good solution to this problem. Overall, the complexity of these authentication libraries made me drop them for the projects. The main solution for ASP.Net Identity is to not use NHibernate, but instead Entity Framework.

Comment: I also ended up with entity framework, but I think there must be a way to do it. I am not actually thinking of following any hack but a genuine and straight forward solution is always welcomed. maybe in future I can put myself on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

One technique is to use basic authentication where the credentials are stored in the header. There is a description of this technique in this article on *[Mixing Forms Authentication, Basic Authentication, and SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/mixing-forms-authentication-basic.html)*. Although the article was written for SimpleMembership a [follow-up article describes how it can also be implemented using ASP.NET Identity](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/12/returning-401-http-status-code-on.html).  Complete source code for these articles with example application can be found in the [SimpleSecurity Project on CodePlex](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/).

Another technique which was just made available in ASP.NET Web API 2 is the use of bearer tokens. There is a good overview on the use of bearer tokens in [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api).

There is an excellent training course on PluralSight titled *[Web API v2 Security](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/webapi-v2-security)* which covers all of these topics with code examples.  You can get a temporary PluralSight account to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding ASP.Net identity; did you have a look at this link to use the corresponding API: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity?

I think that this link could perhaps help you to understand principles of authentication within your RESTful service: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/.

Hope it help you,
Thierry